# While loop clarification in python- error

Tags: python-2.7, loops, while-loop, sum

I have a little experience in python coding and i try to write a code that sum the items in the list except the number 99. This is my code:

```
grade = [100,30,99,85]
i = 0
while grade[i]!=99:
    i = i + grade[i]
print i
```

but i get this error:

```
>>> 
100

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\desktop\test.py", line 3, in <module>
while grade[i]!=99:
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Seems like you are initializing `i` to the letter `o` and not to the number `0`. (**EDIT**: OP updated the question)
2. You have some misconceptions on the difference between an index in a list and 
   an element in the list. In the first iteration you are setting `i` to be equal `100` (`i + grade[i]` is `0 + 100`). As a result, in the second iteration you are trying to access the 100th index of `grade`, which obviously doesn't exist and `IndexError` is being raised.
3. Consider a much simpler approach using Python's built-in `sum`:

   ```
   grade = [100,30,99,85]
   sum_grade = sum(num for num in grade if num != 99)
   print(sum_grade)
   >> 215
   ```

Comment: please explain your second note

Comment: @newGIS added an explanation.

Comment: so, how can i do it in my code, not using the sum function?

Comment: @newGIS `sum = 0 ; for num in grade: ; if num != 99: ; sum += num` Though I don't see a reason why you would do that instead of using `sum`.

Comment: i prefer to use while loop